# Terraform Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I'd like to use email verification in my Cognito User Pool. When I apply my current config, it defaults to "No verification." How do I get it so that the email needs to be verified?

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "main" {
  name = "${var.user_pool_name}_${var.stage}"
  username_attributes = [ "email" ]
  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable             = true
    name                = "name"
    required            = true
  }
  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable             = true
    name                = "email"
    required            = true
  }

  password_policy {
    minimum_length    = "8"
    require_lowercase = true
    require_numbers   = true
    require_symbols   = true
    require_uppercase = true
  }
  mfa_configuration        = "OFF"

  lambda_config {
    custom_message    = aws_lambda_function.custom_message.arn
    post_confirmation = aws_lambda_function.post_confirmation.arn
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aws_cognito_user_pool](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool)

`auto_verified_attributes` attribute of `aws_cognito_user_pool` resource is a list of attributes that you want to enable verification for.

> auto_verified_attributes - (Optional) The attributes to be auto-verified. Possible values: email, phone_number.

[AutoVerifiedAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html#CognitoUserPools-CreateUserPool-request-AutoVerifiedAttributes)

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "main" {
  name = "${var.user_pool_name}_${var.stage}"
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]
  username_attributes = [ "email" ]
  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable             = true
    name                = "name"
    required            = true
  }
  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable             = true
    name                = "email"
    required            = true
  }

  password_policy {
    minimum_length    = "8"
    require_lowercase = true
    require_numbers   = true
    require_symbols   = true
    require_uppercase = true
  }
  mfa_configuration        = "OFF"

  lambda_config {
    custom_message    = aws_lambda_function.custom_message.arn
    post_confirmation = aws_lambda_function.post_confirmation.arn
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this verify the user’s email when they sign up? I’d like to verify their email after they click the link handled by my lambda function executed after signing up.

Comment: @TylerNorlund documentation is fuzzy, if you add this it will give you the result that you are looking for.